# bootstrap glyphicon as button display on table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to the whole bootstrap thing so even though i tried to solve this for last 3 hours, i could'nt. I need a table to have 2 buttons in a cell that looks like a glypicon (so i can add javascript functions to them later). I managed to do this in 2 ways, but the problem is these buttons expand table row a lot. How do i solve this? maybe alternate method of making a button?

Here is how the table looks right now:

https://puu.sh/wbMUf/50a535e0f9.png

here are the lines used to achieve the result for the cell in the first row:

```
<td>
    <p class = "btn"><span class = "fa fa-edit"></span></p>
    <p class = "btn"><span class = "fa fa-trash"></span></p>
</td>
```

and for the cell in the second row:

```
<td>
    <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-link"><span class = "fa fa-edit"></span></button>
    <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-link"><span class = "fa fa-trash"></span></button>
</td>
```

Second option doesnt work, because the glyphs have to styled the same as the rest of the text in the table.

Comment: you can give td width:10%; or less

Comment: this is a nice addition to keep in mind, but doesnt solve the problem, that rows have a lot of extra space at the bottom

Comment: for space, check margin-top and margin-bottom in css.

Comment: yes. you width tip gave me the idea to try modifying margin, border, padding of the element. that did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can give `td width:10%;` or less.

for extra space, check `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` in `css`.

Comment: though it works better if i apply it to the buttons itself rather than td

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

https://jsfiddle.net/7h4qqx44/2/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container style="margin-top: 50px;">
<table class="table table-inverse">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Index</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Surname</th>
      <th>Job</th>
      <th>Wage, €</th>
      <th>bla, €</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>bla</td>
      <td>blum</td>
      <td>
        <p class="btn" style="width:10%; padding-bottom:0; margin-bottom:0; border-bottom:0"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></p>
        <p class="btn" style="width:10%; padding-bottom:0; margin-bottom:0; border-bottom:0"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"></th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
      <td>bla</td>
      <td>blum</td>
      <td>
       <p class="btn" style="width:10%; padding-bottom:0; margin-bottom:0; border-bottom:0"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></p>
        <p class="btn" style="width:10%; padding-bottom:0; margin-bottom:0; border-bottom:0"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"></th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
      <td>bla</td>
      <td>blum</td>
      <td>
        <p class="btn" style="width:10%; padding-bottom:0; margin-bottom:0; border-bottom:0"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></p>
        <p class="btn" style="width:10%; padding-bottom:0; margin-bottom:0; border-bottom:0"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

In the CSS -

```
 .addSpacing {
  margin-left: 5%;
}
```

You could code functionalities by assigning an id/class to these glyphicons. I hope this helps!

Comment: here is how my code looks now and in fiddle all is nice and all, but when i do it on my laptop locally i have the issue i mentioned before
[link](https://jsfiddle.net/7h4qqx44/3/)

Comment: Can you show the code that you are using? And also any css associated with it?

Comment: here [link](https://jsfiddle.net/NulisDefo/yqvpL1c4/4/)
pretty much all the code there is as of now

Comment: Try clearing cached images and files on your browser. Then run the code again.

Comment: I edited the answer. Make a new test project and add the code in the block above. Then run it and isolate the issue from there.